# how to stop jenkins from wiping out workspace when started new build?

Tags: jenkins

Is there any plugin which provide this facility

I have tried following options

1.Tried exploring jenkins default options
2.I am using cvs scm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins does not do that by default.

In fact, there is a plugin to do the exact opposite to specifically wipe out workspace on every build.

Comment: To which plugin are you referring?

Comment: @Codex24 https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin